# Function not taking variable correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Here is my code:

```
var MakeSessions = 1;
function DestroySession()  {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    if(DestroySessions == 1 || DestroySessions == 2) {
        DestroySessions = 0;

    jQuery('.opc-ajax-loader').show();
                jQuery.ajax({
                url: '../../UnsetPercentPayment.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    ShippingMethod: '1'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {                      
                jQuery('.opc-ajax-loader').hide();
                    jQuery('#ShippingPrice').show();
                        jQuery.each(data.GrandTotal, function(index, GrandTotal) {
                            if(MakeSessions == 1) {
                            jQuery('#NewPrice').text(GrandTotal + ' лвs.');

                            }
                            if(MakeSessions == 2) {
                            MyTotal = GrandTotal / 2;   
                            jQuery('#NewPrice').text(MyTotal + ' лвa.');

                            }                                   
                        });


                }
            });


            MakeSessions = 2;

    }       
}
```

On the first time when function `DestroySession()` runs it MUST have `MakeSessions` as `1` and in that order to run:

```
if(MakeSessions == 1) {
jQuery('#NewPrice').text(GrandTotal + ' лвs.'); 
}
```

However it appears that every **first** time when i run `DestroySessions` it runs this part of code:

```
if(MakeSessions == 2) {
MyTotal = GrandTotal / 2;   
jQuery('#NewPrice').text(MyTotal + ' лвa.');                                    
}
```

And that is the problem i do not understand.. Why when MakeSessions is 1 it runs the code for MakeSessions = 2 ?

Can you help me out resolve this problem?

Comment: because ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: The logic here is frankly all over the place. You should have a read of asynchronous principles.

Comment: How can i make this thing work, can you help me out ?

Comment: By not setting MakeSessions to 2 before the ajax success callback runs.

Comment: Exactly what @KevinB said. That MakeSession on the bottom line. Remove it

Comment: And where i have to place it ? How can i set it ? Can someone make an answer with example. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
    }
});
MakeSessions = 2;
```

to

```
        MakeSessions = 2;
    }
});
```

Comment: When i do that on the second run of `DestroySession` it is not running the code for `MakeSessions == 2`. When i check the console it says that MakeSessions is 2 after the first run of the function, but on the second run it just not run the code for MakeSessions == 2. Why ?

Comment: Sounds like a new question.